# AngularJS-Modify NgBoilerPlate template to modify the title of the webpage

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

Have downloaded NgBoilerPlate from https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp.
Using it as a template to build a website.
The flow is as follows-

**index.html**

```
 <li ui-sref-active="active">
              <a href ui-sref="home">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate', [
  'templates-app',
  'templates-common',
  'ngBoilerplate.home',
  'ngBoilerplate.about',
'ui.router'
])
```

**Home.js**

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.home', [
  'ui.router',
  'plusOne'
])

/**
 * Each section or module of the site can also have its own routes. AngularJS
 * will handle ensuring they are all available at run-time, but splitting it
 * this way makes each module more "self-contained".
 */
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Home' }
  });
})
```

Now when the homeTab is clicked-
the title is shown as **Home|ngBoilerplate**

How to get rid of **|ngBoilerPlate** from title.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to this [link](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/src/app/app.js)
2. What you need to change is line number 19

   `$scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle + ' | ngBoilerplate' ;`

Comment: @Rehan Here in stack-overflow we do up-vote instead of saying thanks :)